# Cannot Make a Static Reference.. or Unhandled Exception Type

Tags: java

I'm having a problem. I am trying to reference the `displayList()` method in the 2nd block below from the `execute()` method in the 1st block.

The way I've wrote it down below though, gives me the error `"cannot make a static reference to a non-static method".`

If I try to make the `displayList()` method static, then I get the same exact error for the scanner object inputFile because displayList cannot see it. This then requires me to make inputFile and the string file both static as well. But then I get the problem that the inputFile line throws  - it says that I have an unhandled exception `FileNotFoundException`.

Then since every single thing is static, I can't use the constructor for the `List` class I made for handling this error.

Ok. So these are the relevant parts of code:

```
    static void execute(int choice){
        switch (choice){

            case 1:List.displayList();
                   runNextLoop();
                   break;

            case default:return;

        }
    }
```

and

```
    static class List{  

        String file = "List.txt";
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner (new FileReader(file));

        public List() throws IOException{
            }

        void displayList(){
            while (inputFile.hasNextLine()){
                System.out.println(inputFile.nextLine());                   
            }

        }
```

If I make all the members and methods of List static, then I can't handle the exception. If I don't, then I can't make proper reference from outside the class towards the method I want to call.

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Instantiate an Object of type List.

Answer (score 1):

If I follow you, change this

```
case 1:List.displayList();
```

to

```
case 1:new List().displayList(); // <-- not static.
```

You may need to actually pass in a List reference (bad name, since it collides with `java.util.List`) -

```
static void execute(List list, int choice){
  switch (choice) {
  case 1: // <-- I assume you have more cases and this is just a short excerpt.
    list.displayList();
    runNextLoop();
    break;
  case default:
    return;
  }
}
```